# use namespace in @param

Tags: php, namespaces, phpdoc

Is it good practice to include namespaces for classes in @param annotations? I know that phpdoc does not support namespaces, but how will other tools like phpdox or Doxygen act?

Which way is better / more common?

```
namespace foo\someNamespace;
use foo\someOtherNamespace\MyOtherClass;

--- with namespace ---

/**
 * @param \foo\someOtherNamespace\MyOtherClass $otherClass
 */
class myClass(MyOtherClass $otherClass)
{
    // do something
}

--- without namespace ---

/**
 * @param MyOtherClass $otherClass
 */
class myClass(MyOtherClass $otherClass)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: +1 I personally always use the full namespace \Root\MyClass to make mass find-replace operations easier if I change things ... but I also generally avoid `use` statements with my namespaces because I think it makes it more difficult to understand what's going on in my code.

Comment: My convention is to **always** use the FQN in Docbocks. Without the leading backslash:

  _foo\someOtherNamespace\MyOtherClass $otherClass_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace is a part of the complete name of the class. So if you wouldn't add the namespace to the classname in @param you would give a wrong type.

Personally I think namespaces will become very soon the main criteria for the organization of classes in PHP. So the documentation tools will all have to use them.